# Rails - Class not working for linkto to a controller/action

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I needed to underline the active menu item for a submenu. I found I could use the following in my menu. I could do that by applying class:

`<li><%= link_to "* RFQ", rfq_path(1), class: get_rfqs_class() %></li>`

and have a helper item of

```
  def get_rfqs_class
    if controller_name == 'rfqs'
      return 'active'
    end
  end
```

I have a get_xxx_class() for each item and a corresponding helper.

That works great. However, I needed to do a little different link_to for another menu item

```
    <li> <%= link_to "Pre Production Meeting",  controller: 
'pre_production_meetings', action: 'show', id: 1 , 
op_id: $current_opportunity, class: get_pre_production_meetings_class() %> </li>
```

The problem is that the different link_to format results in the underline not showing. If I do an inspect, it does show the class as active but I don't see the underline

```
<a href="/pre_production_meetings/1?class=active">Pre Production Meeting</a>
```

I tried using divs and spans with the following code but had no luck.

```
   <% if controller_name == 'pre_production_meetings' then %>
                <li> <%= link_to "Pre Production Meeting",  controller: 'pre_production_meetings', action: 'show', id: 1 , op_id: $current_opportunity, class: get_pre_production_meetings_class() %> </li>
          <% else %>
                <li> <%= link_to "Pre Production Meeting", controller: 'pre_production_meetings', action: 'show', id: 1 , op_id: $current_opportunity %></li>

          <% end %>
```

Is there something where using a link_to to a controller/action the way I did will prevent the class from being properly applied?

Also, I inspected the styles for a menu item that was working as expected

```
ul.art-hmenu>li>a.active {
    padding: 0 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #145366;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If I inspect the pre production meetings style, I don't see the a.active but see a.hover

```
ul.art-hmenu>li>a:hover, .desktop ul.art-hmenu>li:hover>a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

If I change the text-decoration to underline, then I see the underlining as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That instance of link_to uses this format:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

You need to surround your url options in curly braces so the link looks like this:

```
<a href="/pre_production_meetings/1" class="active">
```

Your class has been embeded into the url rather than the html.

This should solve your problem:

```
<%= link_to "Pre Production Meeting",
            {controller: 'pre_production_meetings', action: 'show', id: 1 ,
              op_id: @current_opportunity},
            class: get_pre_production_meetings_class() %>
```

Also, the $ is probably a typo.  I'm assuming it is an @.